# React not able to remember component state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, lazy-loading

I am using reactjs 16.x version. I have sidebar which have multiple navigation options. when i moved from one navigation to  another navigation, component gets build every time. which is not very efficient because it makes call to API. Once a component built and if i am not refreshing the page. It should not rebuild again.
I am using lazy loading. Could anyone please let me know what could be the problem.
Not managing all the state with redux.

Comment: If you don't want to load the data from the server, you'll have to cache it somewhere on the client. A global variable is a good pragmatic first implementation.

Comment: You may also want to look into the https://swr.vercel.app/ library ; it does caching fetches for you.

Comment: Provide some code.

Comment: angular by default remember the components. i am wondering what i am missing in reactjs .